# SAPUI5 Multiple Values in a single filter

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5 and excuse me if my question sounds basic. I am trying to set multiple values to a single filter for Odata read request. I need to get the values of column from a table and bind put the values in a filter. I am not able to get it right. Thanks in advance
The response will read the values and default the values on UI.

```
var oModel = oTable.getModel();
            var aItems = oTable.getItems();
            var lFilterArt;
            for (var iRowIndex = 0; iRowIndex < aItems.length; iRowIndex++) {
                var lArticle= oModel.getProperty("Article", aItems[iRowIndex].getBindingContext());
                lFilterArt= new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                    path: "Article",
                    operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
                    value1: lArticle
                });

            }

            var aFilter = new Array();
            aFilter.push(lFilterArt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aFilters = [];
for (var iRowIndex = 0; iRowIndex < aItems.length; iRowIndex++) {
    var lArticle= oModel.getProperty("Article", aItems[iRowIndex].getBindingContext());
    var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Article", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, lArticle);
    aFilters.push(oFilter);
}

this._oControl.bindItems({
   path: "model>/DataSet",
   filters: [
       new Filter({
            filters: aFilters,
            and: false // Defaults to true in which case all filters must match, when set to false it behaves like an OR.
        })
    ],
    …
});
```